# Office365 Unified APi Webhooks

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office365api

I decided to make my apps working with the Unified(1).

So once the user is registered (bearer auth), i stored in db refresh_token, access_token.

I couldn't find a way to register the webhooks simply via the Unified API (and thus with the same access_token i use for simple api query), because under my Office365 unified api preview, i don't have such options as listed in this picture

https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC803864.png

Something Like:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/subscriptions/start?contentType=Audit.SharePoint

Am i missing something **or i actually need to redirect once again my user for granting authorization to Office365 Management API** and store more new tokens in db ?

Thanks a lot to anyone that could clarify this to me ;)

Kind Regards

Steve

(1)Finally an api that make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Office 365 Management Activity API currently requires a different token than the Office 365 Unified API. You will not be able to register a webhook for Office 365 Management Activity API using the Office 365 Unified API token. We are working on convergence and the Office 365 Management Activity API will be part of the Office 365 Unified API in the near future.